# Test the Excel data whether exist or not in Excel sheet

Tags: python, excel, pytest

Excel data:
Name
Scott
Boo
Flo
Garg

Test the data whether name exist or not in the Excel sheet using pytest setup and teardown methods
Condition: the code contains in two .py file one is excel.py another one is test.py

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Hi with current state of your post your objective is unclear. If you edit with clear explanation and include your script/results it would be much better.

If you want to read excel while you can use Pandas Library, read excel with pandas.read_excel and assign it as DataFrame, for more information check below link.

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html